# Как запретить админу редактировать поле Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, forms

Есть такая модель в models.py:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    date_started = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    date_ended = models.DateField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
```

Эта модель регистрируется в admin.py:

```
from .models import Test

admin.site.register(Test)
```

И мне надо сделать так, чтобы в админке можно было добавлять объекты для Test и выбирать что угодно, но нельзя было редактировать поле date_started после того как объект уже был создан. То есть, можно выбрать дату при создании, но нельзя редактировать после. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблему решил так:

admin.py

```python
from .models import Test

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('date_started',)

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете сделать только для чтения в примере админ не может изменить "date_started"

```
class TestInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Test
    exclude = ['name']
    readonly_fields=('date_started', )
```

Comment: Попытался так сделать, получил TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Comment: @Blazzerrr этот код не может выдать такую ошибку, вероятно вы сами накосячили где-то в другом месте

Comment: В этом коде может быть другая ошибка, из-за того что инлайн и модель имеют ожно и тоже имя